# How to find last item by parameter (SQL)?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query to search for some itens in a history. Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM HISTORY WHERE DOCUMENT IN ('DOC1','DOC2','DOC3') ORDER BY DOC ASC, CREATION_DATE DESC;
```

This query return me a list like this:

```
ID | DOC | CREATIONDATE

6  | DOC1 | 12/12/2022

3  | DOC1 | 11/11/2022

5  | DOC2 | 12/12/2022

2  | DOC2 | 11/11/2022

4  | DOC3 | 12/12/2022

1  | DOC3 | 11/11/2022
```

But I want just the most recent item by doc. For example:

```
ID | DOC | CREATIONDATE

6  | DOC1 | 12/12/2022

5  | DOC2 | 12/12/2022

4  | DOC3 | 12/12/2022
```

I dont want the old itens. Just last item inserted by document. Someone can help me?

Comment: Why don't you start by allowing a more precise Date format ? It's impossible for you to distinguish which is the last document created. And then you ll be able to add 'LIMIT 1' at the end of your query

Comment: @jozinho22 Oracle does not support the `LIMIT` keyword (instead, either use `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` or, depending on version, filter on the `ROWNUM` pseudo-column after ordering). However, none of those would limit the rows in each group; they would limit the total number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to rank them by `creation_date` in descending order, and pick the first one.

```
  SELECT id, doc, creation_date
    FROM (SELECT id,
                 doc,
                 creation_date,
                 RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY doc ORDER BY creation_date DESC) rnk
            FROM history
           WHERE document IN ('DOC1', 'DOC2', 'DOC3'))
   WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY doc
```